# ActiveAdmin - Filter with default value

Tags: activeadmin

Would like to know is that possible to have filter with default value with active admin? This will be helpful for preloading the data for the admin user.

```
filter  :country, :default=>'US'
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do it by defining before_filter

```
  before_filter :only => [:index] do
    if params['commit'].blank?
       #country_contains or country_eq .. or depending of your filter type
       params['q'] = {:country_eq => 'US'} 
    end
  end
```

UPD:

in some cases you need to set filter if params[:q] is empty or params[:scope] empty

so this might work better

```
  before_filter :only => [:index] do
    if params['commit'].blank? && params['q'].blank? && params[:scope].blank?
       #country_contains or country_eq .. or depending of your filter type
       params['q'] = {:country_eq => 'US'} 
    end
  end
```

Comment: This should go in a controller block inside the app/admin/model.rb file . e.g.

    controller do
      before_filter...
    end

Comment: @patrick-davey, check example https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/How-to-disable-sidebar .... it is the same but shorter

Comment: This snippet has the problem of clearing out all a user's filters when switching between scopes.

Comment: it is before_action as of Rails 5

Answer (score 10):

Adapted Fivells answer to work correctly with scopes and downloads. Feels hacky but seems to do the job. Annotated intention in comments.

```
  before_filter only: :index do
    # when arriving through top navigation
    if params.keys == ["controller", "action"]
      extra_params = {"q" => {"country_eq" => "US"}}

      # make sure data is filtered and filters show correctly
      params.merge! extra_params

      # make sure downloads and scopes use the default filter
      request.query_parameters.merge! extra_params
    end
  end
```

Comment: before_filter is deprecated, should use before_action instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16519841/1442987

Answer (score 2):

Fixing issue with **"Clear Filters"** button breaking, updated answer building on previous answers:

Rails now uses `before_action` instead of `before_filter`. It belongs in the controller like so:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  controller do
    before_action :set_filter, only: [:index]

    def set_filter
      # when arriving through top navigation
      if params.keys == ["controller", "action"]
        extra_params = {"q" => {"country_eq" => "US"}}

        # make sure data is filtered and filters show correctly
        params.merge! extra_params

        # make sure downloads and scopes use the default filter
        request.query_parameters.merge! extra_params
      end
    end
    params.delete("clear_filters") #removes "clear_filters" if it exists to clear it out when not needed
  end
end
```

Note, ActiveAdmin uses ransack for queries (ex. `{"q" => {"country_eq" => "US"}}`), check out https://activerecord-hackery.github.io/ransack/getting-started/search-matches for more matches if you need something more complex than `"_eq"`.

Also, previous answers leave the **"Clear Filters"** button broken. It doesn't clear the filters, the filters set here are simply re-applied.

To fix the **"Clear Filters"** button, I used this post as a guide [How to keep parameters after clicking clear filters in ActiveAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708691/how-to-keep-parameters-after-clicking-clear-filters-in-activeadmin).

```
#app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js
# Making clear filter button work even on pages with default filters 
    
    $ ->
      $('.clear_filters_btn').click ->
        if !location.search.includes("clear_filters=true")
          location.search = "clear_filters=true"
```

This removes all search params (ie filters) and adds `"clear_filters=true"` so the controller can tell the request came from the **"Clear Filters"** button.

Answer (score 0):

```
before_action  only: [:index] do
  if params['commit'].blank?
    extra_params = {"country_eq" => "US"}
    params['q'] = {} if params['q'].blank?
    params['q'].merge! extra_params

    request.query_parameters.merge! extra_params
  end
end
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.